# Assign selected value to be the POST value

Tags: php, html, ajax

I am trying to make a selected value to be the POST value in a shopping cart.

The snippet is:

```
<div class="extra-option">
  <ul>
    <li><span>Size:</span></li>
    <? foreach ($product->extra_options as $option):
      $control_name = 'grouped_products[' . $product->id . '][product_extra_options]['.$option->option_key.']';
      $posted_options = post('grouped_products[' . $product->id . '][product_extra_options]', array());
      $is_checked = isset($posted_options[$option->option_key]);
    ?>
    <input name="<?= $product->id ?>"
      <?= radio_state($is_checked) ?> 
      id="extra_option_<?= $option->id ?>"
      value="<?= $option->option_key ?>"
    type="radio"/>
    <label for="extra_option_<?= $option->id ?>"><?= h($option->description) ?>:</label>
    <? endforeach ?>
  </ul>
  <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
```

The AJAX Handler snippet is:

```
function on_addProductGroupToCart($controller) {
  foreach(post('grouped_products', array()) as $product_id => $product) {
    $_POST['product_cart_quantity'] = 1;
    $_POST['product_id'] = $product_id;
    $_POST['product_options'] = $product['product_options'];
    $_POST['product_extra_options'] = $product['product_extra_options'];
    $controller->exec_action_handler('shop:on_addToCart');
  }
}
```

The $POST snippet that I know I will have to work with is

```
$_POST['product_extra_options'] = $product['product_extra_options'];
```

If left as is, than the error that I receive is: "**Undefined index:  product_extra_options**"

So, how can I assign the POST variable to be the selected value?

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 1):

You should never assign a value to $_POST[] or $_GET[] - only retrieve the values from them.
To fill the $_POST variables you'll need to submit data via a form.

Answer (score 0):

You assign post variables through the value attribute (or their text if it is a text box) with the POST array key being the name attribute.  For example:

```
<input type="text" name="myInput" />
```

Now, when the form is submitted, you grab the text they entered by using:

```
$_POST['myInput']
```

For something like a checkbox (or radio button), it's the value attribute that assigns the content of the POST variable:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="myCheckbox" value="thisIsChecked" />
```

Now, you would see whether or not it is checked with a simple conditional:

```
if (!empty($_POST['myCheckbox'])) {
   do something; }
```

You can make these attributes dynamic with PHP as well, as it appears you already know.  Example:

```
<?php foreach ($myArray as $arrayValue) {
echo '<input type="checkbox" name="'.$arrayValue.'" value="thisIsChecked" />
}
```